# Link to users blog posts wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I would like to add a link on my template to link to the users own blog posts the code i have tried using is `<li><a href="?author=<?php the_author_ID(); ?>">test</a></li>`.

Edit, had a typo on the code on here and the url that it takes you to is just `?author=`

Comment: you have a typo here `</a></</li>` it should be `</a></li>`

Comment: cool cheers ill edit that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple.

you can use wordpress user list plugins instead of writing codes.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-list/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-users-list/

Comment: well i want a link on the main menu to link to that users posts will this do it?

Comment: @ConnorCushionMulhall In such case you to follow what NullPoiиteя as said.

Comment: thats just what i typed on here it only takes me to '?author=' i need it to take me to eg '?author=1'

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you want to print number only in the URL. just echo the_author_ID().

```
<li><a href="?author=<?php echo the_author_ID(); ?>">test</a></li>
```

Comment: the_author_ID() is deprecated. Please use                         <?php the_author_meta( $field, $userID ); ?> You may refer this url http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_author_meta